# Netty doesn't allow pipe symbol | and throws Exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, netty

My Endpoint is `/mz/api/mot/pol/re/pt?Output=1|920222|R1205200130|Success|`

I am using a Gateway application on Spring Boot which runs on Netty

and facing below exception,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 46: 
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at reactor.netty.http.HttpOperations.resolvePath(HttpOperations.java:300) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.<init>(HttpServerOperations.java:128) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:157) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.4.RELEASE.jar:0.9.4.RELEASE]
    at
```

The same error happens in Tomcat also and I solved it by setting `relaxedQueryChars` property. Kindly suggest how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This ihas nothing to do with Netty whatsoever. You have created an invalid URL. You will have to encode the query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to encode the pipes in your query string for netty. The "|" will become %7C

So this: `/mz/api/mot/pol/re/pt?Output=1%7C920222%7CR1205200130%7CSuccess`

Becomes: `/mz/api/mot/pol/re/pt?Output=1%7C920222%7CR1205200130%7CSuccess

There are lots of tools that will URL encode that string for you if you have control over the client side.

See also:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is I cannot encode the url. This url has been redirected to my service from some 3rd party.

Comment: @HannahShanthini The client did encode it, and your framework decoded it. You now have to encode it yourself again.